# How to setup Postfix with Opendkim to automatically sign PHP emails?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dkim, milter

I've found that:

- submitted emails are signed properly (ie those sent with MUA's like
  Outlook and Thunderbird)
- command-line sent emails are signed properly

**emails sent with PHP**, in particular case PHPMailer (non-smtp submitted, ordinary PHP `mail()`) **are signed incorrectly.**

I have heard about phpMailDomainSigner, which is kind of hack approach, and I would like to solve this at the top - MTA / milter level if possible.

Here are:

*/etc/opendkim.conf*

```
# Log to syslog
Syslog                  yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
#UMask                  002
# dkim-milter (2.5.2.dfsg-1ubuntu1) hardy:
# Disable new umask option by default (not needed since Ubuntu default
# uses a TCP socket instead of a Unix socket).

# Attempt to become the specified userid before starting operations.
#UserID                 105 # 'id postfix' in your shell


Domain                  mysubdomain.domain.tld
KeyFile                 /etc/mail/mail.private
Selector                mail

# Common settings. See dkim-filter.conf(5) for more information.
AutoRestart             yes
Background              yes
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
DNSTimeout              5
Mode                    sv
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
SubDomains              no
#UseASPDiscard          no
#Version                rfc4871
X-Header                no

Statistics              /var/log/dkim-filter/dkim-stats
```

*/etc/default/opendkim*

```
SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"
```

*/etc/postfix/main.cf (last lines of config file)*

```
# DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
```

Comment: AFAIK the PHP mail command is using `sendmail` on *nix (see [SO: How does PHP's `mail` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811711/how-does-phps-mail-work), which is also used by `mailx`. So check the PHP-config on sending mails, post it here along with logs (so we know where the mail comes from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `php mail()`  sent emails for Proper `SMTP From` aka `Envelope From` headers. If they don't have something like `sender@mysubdomain.domain.tld` as `SMTP From` address, opendkim won't sign them as you have `Domain  mysubdomain.domain.tld` in your `/etc/opendkim` file.